# While looping and variable initialization

Tags: c#

In following sinppet of code, I would like to ask: How does the author evaluates the variable 'line' in the **while loop** before he initialize it with a value?

```
StreamReader myReader = new StremReader("Values.txt");

string line = "";

while (**line != null**)

{

    line = myReader.ReadLine();
    if (line != null)
        console.WriteLine(line);
}

myReader.Close();

console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: hmm the variable is initalized? An empty string is not the same as a `null` reference

Answer (score 4):

It *is* initialized with a value: the empty string:

```
string line = "";
```

Even if it didn't have a value and was `null`, it's still possible to test whether it is null with a comparison like in that `while` loop.

Now, this is what an uninitialized variable looks like:

```
string line; // Help! I'm only declared!
while (line != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Trying to compile that would give you this error: "Use of unassigned local variable 'line'". But assigning any value, including `""` or `null` would make things right again.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy to read way:

```
string line;
while((line = myReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

As for the author's snippet of code you provided, line is initialized to an empty string.  Because of this, it always will go into the `while` loop at least one time.  Then it grabs a line from the reader, does stuff with it if it isn't null, and moves on.  I would never write it like that, as you are doing too many checks that way.  Might as well do a single assignment & check in one line.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** `line`  variable is already initialized with empty string `""`.

Regarding the given example of code, i would suggest to use `using` construct to ensure that un-managed code is disposed asap.

```
using (StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("Values.txt"))
            {
                string line = "";
                while (line != null)
                {

                    line = myReader.ReadLine();
                    if (line != null)
                        console.WriteLine(line);
                }

                //myReader.Close();
                console.ReadLine();
            };
```